# Anime/cartoon about battles taking place on a floating arena and the fighters would take control of characters from cards or something

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I've been trying to find a very specific show I watched as a child. It would have been on TV at some point between 1995-2002 or so. I'm not sure if it was a rerun of the show or if it was the first time it ran on TV.

Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of details about it and I've spent years searching online and haven't found it yet.

From what I remember, it had something to do with fighting. I think the battles were to protect something, but they were always one-on-one battles. More like the bad guy would challenge the good guy to a fight, I think. All of the battles took place on a floating arena and I think the fighters would take control of characters from cards or something like that. They would show up on the arena, either appearing from the cards themselves or through a portal.

I know that isn't a lot of detail to work with, but it's all I can remember. I can say for certain that it isn't *Chaotic* and I don't believe it's *Shinzo* either, but I'm going to look into that one again just to be certain.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd love to hear them. This has been bothering me for years and I would love to be able to figure it out.

Comment: yugioh is from 1999- its one on one battles mostly and card based. might consider looking into this

Comment: You could look into Duel Masters (2002) I cant find if it has the floating arena but it has the monster summoning elements.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the characters? What the MC was like?

Comment: @KymNT it's definitely not Yu-Gi-Oh. That was staple in my household when I was growing up lol

Comment: @knightwatch i looked into Duel Masters and it doesn't seem to be that either. It's less of a card game that happens and more like they are picking a character to fight with and they become that character. It's hard to explain. And in truth I'm not entirely sure how much of what I remember is even accurate. I think the main character was like an adult or at least a teen. Visually it was a much sleeker look than you would see with like a show that has a little more childlike animation if the mc was a kid, ya know?

Comment: shaolin showdown has an arena, and they challenge them to a battle. the battles is to protect the artifacts . look into it i guess